# using jsf primefaces button closing a dialog depending on a boolean at oncomplete event

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

I have a problem. I have a JSF Primefaces environment, and I would like to set the password. In the bean there is a method, it can throw exception or set the doneChange boolean to true.

I want the following run:
If the doneChange boolean is true, just close the dialog where the button is, and open an another.
Here is the code of the button:

```
                <p:commandButton id="changeButtonId" 
                             type="submit" 
                             value="#{msg.changePassword}" 
                             ajax="true" 
                             action="#{changePasswordController.changePassword}" 
                             update=":changePasswordFormId :actionSuccessDialogId" 
                             oncomplete="if(#{changePasswordController.doneChange}){actionSuccessDialogVar.show()}; if(#{changePasswordController.doneChange}){changePWDialog.hide();}">
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{functionSuccessBean.actionName}" value="#{msg.changePassword}"/>
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{functionSuccessBean.description}" value="#{msg['actionSuccess']}"/>
            </p:commandButton>
```

the problem is: I debugged when I click on this button, before the oncomplete called the doneChange set to true. I have only one suspection: when the button is rendered, the oncomplete event is determined. Because when I open this dialog again, that doneChange is still true and works as I want. I ran out of ideas how to make it work.
How can I make it react the doneChange boolean in real time? Does it work with some binding? I tried primefaces home tutorials but with no success.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution by a help of a non-stackoverflow friend. It appears I used it wrong way, and needed to add a callbackparam.

I needed to add in the Bean:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam(
  "doneChangeParam", 
  doneChange
);
```

And oncomplete changed to:

```
oncomplete="if(
  args &amp;&amp; args.doneChangeParam)
  {
    actionSuccessDialogVar.show(); changePWDialog.hide();
  }"
```